# Execute function with onShow with Materialize doesnt work

Tags: javascript, materialize

I'm trying to call a function when the tab is changed. Nothing is happening though, does someone see my mistake?

V1:

```
var elem = $('.tabs')
var options = { onShow: tabChange}
var init_tabs = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
var instance_tabs = M.Tabs.getInstance(elem);

function tabChange() {
    console.log("tab has changed");
}
```

V2:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var elem = document.getElementById("periodselector");
    var options = { onShow: tabChange }
    var init_tabs = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
});

function tabChange() {
    console.log("tab has changed");
}
```

here the HTML:

```
                <div class="card-tabs">
                    <ul class="tabs tabs-fullwidth " id="periodselector">
                        <li class="tab col s3 "><a id="daySelector" class=" " href="#DayTab">Tag</a> </li>
                        <li class="tab col s3 "><a id="monthSelector" class=" " href="#MonthTab">Monat</a> </li>
                        <li class="tab col s3 "><a class=" " href="#YearTab">Jahr</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: Hello. Please also post yout html markup

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Please may you update the code to be a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

On the `elem` var you should put the javascript object instead of the jQuery one.

From materialize doc:

```
var instance = M.Tabs.init(el, options);

  // Or with jQuery

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

Try `var elem = $('.tabs')[0]` or `var elem = $('.tabs').eq(0)`

I have not tested this but I believe it will fix your problem

Comment: Sorry that didn't help, I also tried the following implementation:
```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        var elem = document.getElementById("periodselector");
        var options = { onShow: tabChange }
        var init_tabs = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
    });
```